# JSON Message post from GWT to Spring MVC Controller

Tags: json, spring, gwt, post, controller

I am trying to post a JSON message from GWT to a Controller in Spring MVC Framework. The spring controller is receiving request from GWT, but when I print out the request content length and request.toString(), it shows 0 for the content lenght and the output of the request.toString() does not have any content.

**The following is my codes and output:**

The following is my GWT code that perform the posting of JSON message :

```
@UiHandler("saveButton")
void onClick(ClickEvent e) {

    UserAddJSO jso = (UserAddJSO)JavaScriptObject.createObject().cast();
    jso.setFirstName("Alex");
    jso.setLastName("Cheng");

    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "addUser.aj");
    builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    builder.setRequestData(new JSONObject(jso).toString());
    System.out.println("request data :"+builder.getRequestData());

    try
    {
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback()
        {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
            {
                Window.alert("on error");
            }
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
            {
                Window.alert("response received :"+response.getStatusCode());
                Window.alert(response.getText());
            }
        });
    }
    catch (RequestException excp)
    {
        Window.alert("exception catched");
    }
}
```

from the above code you can see i have a print out on the request data, the json string is there.

there following is my Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**/addUser.aj", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<UserAddDTO> getPostStocks(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    List<UserAddDTO> userDTO = new ArrayList<UserAddDTO>();

    JSONObject jObj;
    jObj = new JSONObject(request.getParameterMap());
    System.out.println(jObj.toString());
    System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxx "+request.toString());
    System.out.println("content type :"+request.getContentType());
    System.out.println("inside post method");

    return userDTO;
}
```

The following is the output from the above print out :

```
request data :{"firstName":"Alex", "lastName":"Cheng"}
content type :application/json
content length :0
inside post method
{}
xxxxxxxxxxxxx POST /addUser.aj HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/AlliumApp.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0; Tablet PC 2.0; BRI/2)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

from the above output you can see the JSON message is there inside the request. But when it reached the controller the JSON message is not there anymore. So am i doing the right way for json message posting and receiving?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

POST method

```
builder.setRequestData("jsonParam=" + new JSONObject(jso).toString());
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**/addUser.aj", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces =       "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<UserAddDTO> getPostStocks(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("jsonParam") String jsonParam) {
    ...
    JSONObject jObj;
    jObj = new JSONObject(jsonParam);
}
```

GET method:

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,
                              "addUser.aj?jsonParam=" + new JSONObject(jso).toString());
```

and in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "**/addUser.aj", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =   "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<UserAddDTO> getPostStocks(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("jsonParam") String jsonParam) {
    ...
    JSONObject jObj;
    jObj = new JSONObject(jsonParam);
}
```

Comment: Hi nDijax, thanks for your help. i tried both of the post and get method. the get method work perfectly fine, but the post method is not working. Witht post method I get the response status code error 400, i guess it is due to the controller does not received any content with the parameter of "jsonParam" or i should say there is not content at all from the post method. Seems like something wrong with the method of       "builder.setRequestData("jsonParam=" + new JSONObject(jso).toString());"  So what you think nDijax?

Comment: can you log the request post data?

Comment: Yes, i am able to print out the content of the request data in GWT client side. After posted to server side (controller) the request content is empty but the content type is there.

Comment: maybe try with the default content-type